# How to do polymorphic relations in symfony / doctrine?

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine

I have a few Entities, for example "User" and "Room", "House", "City". The list could be increased. Their primary key is always an UUID.

Now I want to create an Entity to describe, what permissions a User has to the Rooms, Houses and Cities. I don't want to create a linking table for each Entity. So could I do something like

```
UserUUID         => User UUID
PermissionUUID   => Permission UUID 
EntityClass      => Room, House, City, and so on
EntityUUID       => UUID of Room, House, etc. depends on EntityClass
```

Would be great if you could give me an example on how to solve this problem.

Thanks in advance!